# Does convergence of Bernstein polynomials imply convergence of its coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, uniform-convergence, approximation-theory

Assume a sequence of Bernstein polynomials $\{p_N(t)\}_{N=1}^\infty$ uniformly converges to a continuous function $f(t)$ on $[0,t_f]$. Is it true that the Bernstein coefficients of $p_N(t)$ (e.g., $p_{iN}$) converge to $f(it_f/N)$?

Essentially, this would be the converse of the Bernstein approximation theorem, which states that if $f(t)$ is continuous, then the Bernstein polynomial 
$$g_N(t) = \sum_{I=0}^N f\left(i \frac{t_f}{N}\right) b_{i,N}(t)$$
uniformly converges to $f(t)$.

This is what I have so far:
Let $g_N(t)$ be a Bernstein polynomial approximation of $f(t)$, namely
$$g_N(t) = \sum_{I=0}^N f\left(i \frac{t_f}{N}\right) b_{i,N}(t),$$
where $b_{i,N}(t)$ is the Bernstein basis. Then,
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} g_N(t) = f(t) \, .$$
On the other hand, by assumption we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} p_N(t) = f(t) \, .$$
Thus, combining the equations above we get
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} (g_N(t) - p_N(t)) = 0\, , $$
which implies
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^N \left(f\left(i \frac{t_f}{N}\right) - p_{iN}\right)b_{i,N}(t) = 0\, .$$
Finally, the result above implies
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(f\left(i \frac{t_f}{N}\right) - p_{iN}\right)=0 \, , \quad \forall i \in \{0,\ldots , N\} \, ,$$
which proves the result.

However, I am not quite sure about the last implication. It should be true given the positiveness and partition of unity property of the Bernstein basis, but I am unable to prove it.